# SCP copying issue

Tags: scp

I want to copy the files close to 500 GB from server to my local machine but I have very poor connectivity so the connection breaks in between. Every time when I run scp again, it is copying and overwriting the same set of files again rather than skipping the successfully copied files. However, this way I may not be able to copy the data ever. Please help

Comment: Use rsync with the update option -u, this will only copy data which changed or is not yet copied. `rsync -avu <source> <destination>`

Answer (score 1):

Use rsync.

```
rsync -avr --inplace user@source:/path/ /path/to/detination/
```

This will copy files, and keep partially written files so that you can resume transfer in middle of a file if it is interrupted for any reason.

Comment: is this coomand run from the local machine?

Comment: You can run it from either machine.  Either the source or destination can include the machine name in "user@hostname:/path"